# Ember computed property for "not equal to current route"

Tags: ember.js, properties

Curious what do as equivalent to the following computed property. In fact, there is no notEqual method built in to Ember's [computed](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject/computed).

```
isNotPizza: computed.notEqual('controllers.application.currentRouteName', 'pizza'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways:

```
import { not, equal } from '@ember/object/computed';

// ...

isPizza: equal('controllers.application.currentRouteName', 'pizza'),
isNotPizza: not('isPizza'),
```

or, you could make a not Equal by doing:

```
import { not, equal } from '@ember/object/computed';

isNotPizza: not(equal('controllers.application.currentRouteName', 'pizza')),
```

Might need to use this though: https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-macro-helpers don't remember if this is natively supported.

If you happen to be on ember-canary (using native classes and decorators), you could do:

```
@not
@equal('controllers.application.currentRouteName', 'pizza')
isNotPizza;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom computed property:

```
isNotPizza: computed('controllers.application.currentRouteName', function () {
  return 'pizza' !== this.get('controllers.application.currentRouteName');
}),
```

Comment: if you have ember >= 31, you can do `this.controllers.application.currentRouteName`